# (MySQL) Select row based off max count and tiebreaker logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that currently pulls the count of a number for each user and the date the record was created.

| user | number | num | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA1 | 2 | 3/1/2022 |
| 1 | BB1 | 2 | 4/1/2022 |
| 1 | CC1 | 1 | 1/1/2020 |

I want the row with the highest count and most recent date as a tiebreaker, in my example, BB1. I'm having a hard time figuring out what steps to take next with my query:

```
SELECT id, number, count(dl.number) as 'num', date_created
FROM some_table
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id, number;
```

I have tried putting this into a subquery to alias, and use max() on count and date_created, but it does not get me what I'm looking for.

Very much appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: save the dates in mysqk format and you have less problems in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the criteria you want in descending order using `ORDER BY`, and then pick the first one only using `LIMIT`:

```
select *
from some_table
where user = 1
order by num desc, date_created desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I’m only looking to select 1 row and not have to use LIMIT. It won’t be just one id every time. Should’ve been more clear in my question

Comment: @nalgenebottle why not using limit ?